# Running PHP Zend Test in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-test

Is it possible to run PHP Zend test cases (those that extend Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase, etc.) through Eclipse PDT?

I would like to be able to run them in a similar fashion as you run JUnit tests in Eclipse, by right-clicking the test file and selecting "Run as a JUnit test case."

I'd love to see the green or red bar instead of having to go to the command line :).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have never been able to get the [SimpleTest Eclipse plugin](http://simpletest.org/en/extension_eclipse.html) to work with PHPUnit based tests, though it's theoretically possible. You can get PHPUnit to run in the Eclipse IDE, but it's in a way that just dumps output to the console. At least, you don't have to leave the IDE then, although you don't get nice red/green reports. If anyone can extend the damn SimpleTest plugin to include PHPUnit, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [MakeGood](https://github.com/piece/makegood) "a continuous test runner to run unit tests on Eclipse PDT"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into the SimpleTest plugin for Eclipse, it has PHPUnit support although I cannot verify if it works or not:

http://www.simpletest.org/

You run tests similarly to JUnit via "Run as SimpleTest", and there is a JUnit-like result view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHPUnit component of the PTI Eclipse plugin: http://www.phpsrc.org/projects/pti-phpunit/wiki/

It will provide you with a test generator, simple ways to run tests and code highlighting to see which test failed where.